# How can I display related items for a restaurant in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, react-router

I'd like to display items on a **new page** that are related to a restaurant when the button is clicked.

[This is how the home page looks when displaying the restaurant component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evEaJ.png)

[This is the directory of my components.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT94k.png)

[This is how the data is stored for a restaurant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5bKD.png)

In this **Restaurant.js**, I would like to link it to '/restaurantdetails' where the button line code is. But how do i pass the restaurant info? Should i re-arrange any of the files? Please provide some guidance to the best way

```
import React from "react";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import ThumbUpAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import moment from "moment";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Restaurant = ({ restaurant, setCurrentId }) => {
  // Style classes
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    // Card Class
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      {/* Restaurant Image*/}
      <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={restaurant.image} title={restaurant.title} />

      {/* Overlay restaurant name with Button for Restaurant details*/}
      <div className={classes.overlay}>
         {/*I WANT TO LINK TO RESTAURANTDETAILS TO DISPLAY THE ITEMS BUT HOW? */}
        <Button component={Link} to="/restaurantdetails:" variant="contained">
          <Typography variant="h6">{restaurant.name}</Typography>
        </Button>

        {/* <Typography variant="body2">{restaurant.description}</Typography> */}
      </div>

      {/* Edit Restaurant Button */}
      <div className={classes.overlay2}>
        <Button
          style={{ color: "white" }}
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setCurrentId(restaurant._id)}
        >
          <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" />
        </Button>
      </div>

      {/* Tags maybe add */}
      <div className={classes.details}>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="h2">
          tags maybe
        </Typography>
      </div>
      {/* Description of Restaurant */}
      <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
        {restaurant.description}
      </Typography>

      {/* Details of Restaurant */}
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          {restaurant.city}, {restaurant.street}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>

      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        {/* Like */}
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
          <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" />
          Like
        </Button>
        {/* Delete */}
        <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={() => {}}>
          <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
          Delete
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Restaurant;
```

Comment: perhaps i could send the restaurant ID to the 'restaurantdetails:ID' component but how?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the ID to the through using the URL.

```js
<Link to={`/restaurantDetails/${restaurant.id}`}>Show details</Link>
```

The `RestaurantDetails` route/component can then read this parameter from the URL and fetch the data for that restaurant from the API.

```js
function RestaurantDetails() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  const [restaurantInfo, setRestaurantInfo] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/restaurantInfo/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setRestaurantInfo(data));
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Restaurant id is: {id}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Links: [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams), [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you... Unfortunately, I cant receive the restaurant data back,

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(restaurantDetails(_id))
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setRestaurantInfo(data));
    console.log("this is restaurantInfo" + restaurantInfo);
    console.log(_id);
  }, [dispatch]);

Comment: I receive this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.json is not a function

Comment: Hmm, strange! Are you sure that your API returns JSON data? Also, here's a guide on how to use the Fetch function which might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch 

Comment: @HT Can you update your question to include that `restaurantDetails` action you are dispatching so we may see what it is returning?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your route like this '/restaurantDetails/:id
2. In restaurant page button update button to use this above link.

   ```
   <div className={classes.overlay}>
     {/*I WANT TO LINK TO RESTAURANTDETAILS TO DISPLAY THE ITEMS BUT HOW? */}
     <Button component={Link} to=`/restaurantdetails/${restaurant.id}` variant="contained">
       <Typography variant="h6">{restaurant.name}</Typography>
     </Button>

     {/* <Typography variant="body2">{restaurant.description}</Typography> */}
   </div>
   ```
3. If you are storing whole data of restaurant in redux store. Make a property in your redux store state as `activeRestaurant = {}`
   Now create a reducer logic and action to find restaurant from stored restaurant data and set this found restaurant as activeRestaurant.
4. On restaurant details page

   ```
   function RestaurantDetails() {
     const selectedId = props.match.params.id;
     const activeRestaurant = useSelector(state => state.activeRestaurant); // fetch reducer state

     useEffect(() => {
       if(selectedId) {
         dispatch(findRestaurant(selectedId)) // redux action
       }
     , [selectedId])

    return <h1>{activeRestaurant.name}</h1>
   }
   ```

P.S. If you are not storing restaurant data in redux. You can use a api request for getting data. You just need to replace `dispatch(findRestaurant(selectedId))` to your api request function.